# .keyup() is only working once, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this pretty simple jquery function, but it seems to work only on the first keyup..

```
$('#cmentuser').keyup(function() {
 var mess = document.getElementById('cmentuser').value;
 var dataString = 'message='+ mess; 

    $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "atuamae.org/comentbyuser.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
 }  
});
});
```

any ideas on how to keep it active?

Comment: Are you overwriting the element that has the `keyup` event bound in the `success` callback? You don't need `getElementById` if using jQuery, as a side note.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) illustrating the problem?

Comment: It might that you change the id or delete it after first press 
Also what the debugger says for you ?

Comment: And why do you think it doesn't work the second time? Success function doesn't do anything!

Comment: (Not an answer to the actual question) `var mess = document.getElementById('cmentuser').value;` should be `this.value;` (or `$(this).val();` if you need jQuery's handling of values, e.g. from `select` boxes and the like). Within a jQuery event hander, `this` refers to the DOM event the handler is hooked up to.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/4kzVn/

Comment: what you are trying to do here, what is job of ajax call and what the success will do, if you are returning the some value in that element on which the keyup is applied than you need to bind the keyup with live method.

Comment: _"Seems to work only on the first keyup"_ - What do you mean "seems"? What is actually happening? Are you logging the requests server-side, or...? (And even if it worked, do you really want to make an ajax request on every keystroke? Five or more requests per second?) Also, unless this is just a cut-down version of the code for purposes of the question, you can delete the first two lines of the function and then in your `ajax()` call have `data : 'message='+this.value`

Comment: what actually happens is that that it only runs if the input is int, if a letter is written it doesn't. strange

Comment: What runs for int values, your server-side code? Sounds like the problem is in your server-side code, not the keyup handler.

Answer (score 3):

It works, also in the following form (changed `mess` into `jQuery(this).val()` and relied on jQuery when encoding the data string):

```
$('#cmentuser').keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "atuamae.org/comentbyuser.php",  
        data: {
            'message': jQuery(this).val()
        },  
        success: function() {
            // success callback
        }  
    });
});
```

Proof that it works: [jsfiddle.net/xfxPR/](http://jsfiddle.net/xfxPR/)

You may be dynamically changing some elements (eg. changing ID or assuming `id` does not need to be unique), or maybe unbinding the event. Just make sure the event is being attached and stays attached to the element you need.

Comment: Depending on what `$(this).val()` returns, it might be a good idea to use `{message: $(this).val()}` to let jQuery take care of encoding.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that change fixes the problem. I went to your jsfiddle, changed the code back to be like in the question with `var mess = document.getElementById("cmentuser").value` and it worked too.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I never said it does not work in the previous form. It is just better to use `jQuery(this).val()` instead of getting element again by ID from the DOM. I said it works in the given form correctly and should be used in the following form instead of the one given by OP. I also mentioned possible reasons that it did not work for OP. Got it?

Comment: Good that you mentioned the other reasons, but the statement "it works in the following form" implies the previous form doesn't work, especially when you didn't otherwise explain _why_ you made that change. If the intention is just to make the code better then it would be better still to use `this.value` (unless it is a select element).

Comment: @nnnnnn: No, it does not imply the other forms are not working. It mentions only that the current form works. But yes, someone **may think** that is the case, thus I corrected my answer. `jQuery(this).val()` is more universal and preferred when working with jQuery.

Comment: @PedroEsperança: I think I know what may be the problem here - I have updated the answer to rely on jQuery when encoding the query string. Check if that works now - it should. I do not know what language do you use on server side, but the value should be available in `message` part of POST request.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#cmentuser').live('keyup',function() {
 var mess = $(this).val();
 var dataString = 'message='+ mess; 
    $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "atuamae.org/comentbyuser.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
 }  
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#cmentuser', function(e) {//try to find lower element then doc
   var dataString = 'message='+ $(e.target).val();

   $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/comentbyuser.php", //no cross domain requests, no need for domain name
      data: dataString,  
      success: function() {}  
   });
});
```

Comment: `e.target` is a DOM element, which has no `.val()`.

Comment: @pimvdb you are absolutly right, ment to write value not val(), but old habbit i suppose. Changed it to a jQuery version instead, just for the hell of it.